# Windows Azure Storage javascript (nodejs) library for browser application

Tags: javascript, azure

I have a case where I would like to list all blobs in windows azure blob storage in a browser application where I dont want the user to submit their storage account credentials to the webserver. Wonder if its possible to use nodejs libraries for windows azure in the browser or I need to implement my own little javascript lib for doing the stuff I need in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look at Node.js SDK. It's for Node.js but I think could be used for browser with some code changes.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/

Comment: Was considering that. If thats they only case I properly will go with WAAD and oauth for signing in and use a service to do the operations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, one simple solution could be to create a **`Shared Access Signature`** on the blob container with **`List`** permission and then doing a [`List Blobs REST API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135734.aspx) call through AJAX. This will return you the list of blobs in XML format which you can parse and present it in the browser.

Comment: The user dont know anything about user other then he has a subscription so creating a shared access signature would mean he had to give the credentials to the server to get the shared access signature?  But I am properly going this way anyway and just use WAAD to get him to sign in and do a web service to get the information as it is alot easier to do all this is c# :)